# AWS S3 Unable to properly get the Object Key if it contains spaces

Tags: shell, amazon-s3

I am trying to reset the `Content-Type` of all of the files in my S3 bucket, while the content type thing is working I am running into issues with some of the folders in my buckets - and it is apparently due to spaces in the folder name.

I have this script

```
#!/bin/bash

S3_BUCKET="mytestbucket"

# List all objects in the S3 bucket recursively
aws s3 ls "s3://${S3_BUCKET}/ Jon Doe/" --recursive | while IFS= read -r line
do
    # OBJECT_KEY=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $4}')
    echo "$line"
    OBJECT_KEY=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $4}')
    echo "$OBJECT_KEY"
    FILE_EXTENSION="${OBJECT_KEY##*.}"  # Extract the file extension

    # Map file extensions to content types
    case "$FILE_EXTENSION" in
        pdf)
            CONTENT_TYPE="application/pdf"
            ;;
        jpg|jpeg)
            CONTENT_TYPE="image/jpeg"
            ;;
        png)
            CONTENT_TYPE="image/png"
            ;;
        mp4)
            CONTENT_TYPE="video/mp4"
            ;;
        wmv)
            CONTENT_TYPE="video/x-ms-wmv"
            ;;
        txt)
            CONTENT_TYPE="text/plain"
            ;;
        *)
            # Default to a generic binary type if the extension is not recognized
            CONTENT_TYPE="application/octet-stream"
            ;;
    esac

    # Update the Content-Type metadata for the object
    aws s3 cp "s3://${S3_BUCKET}/${OBJECT_KEY}" "s3://${S3_BUCKET}/${OBJECT_KEY}" --content-type "${CONTENT_TYPE}"
    # Print a message indicating that the operation is complete for this object
    echo "s3://${S3_BUCKET}/${OBJECT_KEY}"
    echo "Updated Content-Type for $OBJECT_KEY to $CONTENT_TYPE" 
done
```

I expect the $OBJECT_KEY to be something like `s3://mytestbucket/ Jon Doe/filename.jpg` for e.g however I am ending up with
`s3://mytestbucket/Jon`

This script works totally fine with folder paths that doesn't contain any spaces. I have tried several variations of the code for e.g removed `IFS=` from the code, then also something like this

```
# Extract the object key (filename) from the line
OBJECT_KEY=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*\(s3:\/\/.*\)/\1/')

# Skip empty lines
if [ -z "$OBJECT_KEY" ]; then
    continue
fi

# Trim leading and trailing spaces
OBJECT_KEY=$(echo "$OBJECT_KEY" | xargs)
echo "$OBJECT_KEY"
```

Nothing seems to be working.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue by using a different API of the CLI that picked just the object key instead of printing the entire row of data and then trying to pluck the object key out of it, since my folders had spaces inside of it and even at the beginning of the names it was difficult to do it this way.

My new approach was to use the `s3api` `list-objects` that returned just the object key which is all I needed.

```
#!/bin/bash

# List all objects in the S3 bucket recursively
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket mytestbucket --query "Contents[].Key" --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | while IFS= read -r line
do
...
...
... rest of the code
```